# How to show a Plotly plot in a Jupyter's Notebook Python cell output?

Tags: python, plotly-python

Using python this outputs a plot (using Plotly) on the browser:

```
import plotly.express as px

figure = px.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
figure.show()
```

I tried the same code in a Jupyter's Notebook Python cell and I get:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I need to show the plot on the cell's output.

How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Using python this outputs a plot (using Plotly) on the browser:"? What site or how are you getting there? And it's not s notebook or connected to a kernel? And then for "I tried the same code in a Jupyter's Notebook Python cell...", what do you mean? Installed locally? Did you use Anaconda?

Comment: I am using VS Code with the Jupiter extensions. I am able to run a Python.py script which opens the plot on a browser when I run it due to figure.show(). But I am not able to create a plot on a Jupiter notebook? Does this help? I am new to python so maybe I am missing something on your question.

Comment: Definitely helps on the first part. But where are you using Jupyter Noteook?  Your posted code works. I can demonstrate. Go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and click `launch binder`. Select '3D scatter plots via Plotly' from the list of available notebooks and paste in your code. So if you care where it works, which you still haven't described, then you probably need to fix your environment. Assuming wherever you are running things works for Matplotlib plots and other typical notebook code. How recent is the Plotly version there?

Comment: I restarted the kernel and now it works. Thank you.